# Name and/or class of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Does the following graph:

[image]

(with graph6 string `FFzvO`) have a name or belong to a special class?

The DIMACS (bliss) format of it is:

```
p edge 7 14
e 1 4
e 1 5
e 1 6
e 1 7
e 2 4
e 2 5
e 2 6
e 2 7
e 3 4
e 3 5
e 3 6
e 3 7
e 4 6
e 5 7
```

And another image, obtained after a permutation of vertices, is:

[image]

Comment: The graph is 4-regular. Are you looking for something more specific? Where does this graph come from? Is there a context where you care about it that's relevant here?

Comment: I was trying a canonical labeling algorithm and this is the smallest graph where it fails. Maybe another curiosity could be to know if it resembles any category in this [list](https://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/Graphs.html), where the smallest graphs are usually larger than 7 vertices / 14 edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's $\overline{C_3 \cup C_4}$: In your first diagram the vertices 1-2-3 are independent, so the complement of a triangle, and 4-5-6-7 are two independent edges, so the complement of 4-cycle. Every vertex in the co-triangle is adjacent to every vertex in the co-$C_4$.

Edit: Oh, this was supposed to be just a comment.